# Why is my code not working as expected?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code to input few strings and compare the lengths  of the strings and then print the shorter string to console output. but the code isn't working as expected, and upon giving any set of inputs, the output I get is a blank screen (no string gets displayed). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The `input` array has strings supplied by the user and these strings are also present in `a`, so that the line (`string[i] == a[j]`) will execute to true for a specific value in `a`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    char a[m][10], b[m][10]; // will print the shorter out of these two
    for (long i = 0; i < m; i++) cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
    char input[n][10];
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> input[i];
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (long j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (input[i] == a[j]) // checks which set of a,b does this input correspond to
            {
                if (strlen(a[j]) > strlen(b[j])) cout << b[j];
                else cout << a[j];
                if (i < n - 1) cout << " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that something is wrong with the code (`input[i] == a[j]`) but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Since this is tagged as a C++ question, is there any reason that you aren't using `std::string`?

Comment: Your title exactly matches with one of "Vote to close" reason....

Comment: ..because you have not aparrently debugged it.  If you had done any debugging, you would have told us of what you found out, wouldn't you?

Comment: Technically speaking, your program isn't actually C++, because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: I think you need to think about your code more.  Why do you have 2-Dimensional arrays of char? You only need a 1-Dim array of char to store a string. Why is the second dimension of each char array 10? It looks as though the user enters 2 sets of 'm' 10 character strings and then one set of 'n' 10 character strings.

Why do you expect any of the strings in 'input' to be the same as strings in 'a' or 'b'? Why are you only making comparisons when one of the strings in 'a' equals one of the strings in 'input'?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is this comparison:

```
input[i] == a[j]
```

It compares two *pointers*, and not the strings.

Either change to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or use [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).